# HTML Checkbox just returns None as value to my Django views

Tags: python, html, django

I have a very basic question.
I created a checkbox form in HTML and I want to pass the Checkbox data to my Django views.
Now I have the problem, that i just get returned None as a value and i don't know why.

HTML code:

```
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="form-check">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="bb1">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="bb1">
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
```

```
checkbox_input = request.GET.get("bb1")
    print(checkbox_input)
```

should't the output be something like "True", "False" or "on"?
If I render my homepage and submit something, the link looks like this:

127.0.0.1:8000/?value=Hous&checkbox=on

Why can't I grab the value "on"?

I'm sorry I'm so sloppy about the way I phrase things here. I hope you guys can still help me :)

Comment: Did you try `request.GET.get("checkbox")`, since that is the `name` you provided for the checkbox?

Comment: Wow, this was realy obvious :). Thank you, of course it can't work like this ;).

Comment: Did it work for you now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Form elements use their `name` attribute to pass values via form submit, so use

```
checkbox_input = request.GET.get("checkbox");
```

instead of

```
checkbox_input = request.GET.get("bb1");
```

since you named the checkbox "checkbox".